# Hierarchical clustering using Mutual Information as similarity measure?

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, entropy

I want to use [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage) to compute a linkage structure on my data. The similarity measure I need to use is [Mutual Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). I can easily compute a corresponding similarity matrix. However, the `linkage` function only accepts a distance matrix.

Using scipy (or another python lib), how can I compute the linkage structure using Mutual Information as similarity measure?
Can I maybe convert a similiary matrix to a distance matrix?

Comment: `I can easily compute a corresponding similarity matrix. However, the linkage function only accepts a distance matrix`. Similarity and Distance are somewhat similar concepts. Can't you just try to find a nice way to convert similarity to a distance score?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Metric seems interesting, maybe related.

Comment: I should've read the wiki page more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [paragraph on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Metric) that @cel pointed to, the [Jaccard distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) is a distance variant of Mutual Information. The module [distance.pdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) from scipy has support for computing the distance matrix using the Jaccard distance.